# Want to a pre and post character for Multiple macthes in regular expression in Notepad++ with single quotes

Tags: regex, notepad++

Want to replace the below data for every word with single quote before and after. Kindly let me know the regular expression for the same. I have used the one `([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[:|.|,|-])` which matches all the word and I don't know to replace with which one to get the single quote before and after.

Data(Every data is with a tabbed spaced)

```
SystemKey   CompanyName PhysicalAddressLine1    PhysicalAddressLine2    PhysicalCity    PhysicalStateCode   PhysicalProvince    PhysicalZipCode PhysicalCountryCode TaxId   AU  SystemID    OfficerID   MainPhone   OpenDate    ChangeFlag
15524499    Valley Medical Center   hfdfsffgsdhfdsfgsdfgsdfhgdhfgsdfgsgfjgdsContactAddressLine2dsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsddsdsds    NULL    Renton  ww  NULL    ww12    US  NULL    0042585 15524499    6577T   NULL    2015-10-15 00:00:00.000 Y
0007736-000 9700 Pico Corp  9700 W Pico Blvd    NULL    Los Angeles     NULL    90035-4700  US  954456131   0007031 0007736-000 0193T   NULL    1981-12-29 00:00:00.000 Y
00088700    GATEWAY, INC.   14303 Gateway Place NULL    POWAY   NULL    CA  92064   CA  421249184   0008725 00088700    1209T   NULL    1996-08-26 00:00:00.000 Y
00002400    Nash Finch Company  7600 France Ave S   NULL    Minneapolis NULL    ww  554355924   CA  410431960   0008725 00002400    1289T   NULL    1993-10-22 00:00:00.000 Y
00006000    BAE SYSTEMS, Inc.   1601 Research Blvd  NULL    ROCKVILLE   NULL    MD  20850-3173  CA  223537950   0062635 00006000    1236T   NULL    1993-11-23 00:00:00.000 Y
00008714    Schreiber Foods Inc and Affiliated  PO Box 19010    NULL    GREEN BAY   WI  NULL    54307-9010  US  391017450   0048114 00008714    0083T   NULL    2007-09-25 00:00:00.000 Y
00013455    Border States Industries, Inc.  105 25th Street N   fkjsdhjksdhfjsdkfjks    Fargo   NULL    NULL    58102   NULL    450275004   0057221 00013455    1815T   NULL    2010-09-30 00:00:00.000 Y
000160000023    Target Corporation  1000 Nicollet Mall  NULL    MINNEAPOLIS MN  NULL    55402   US  043327228   0008725 000160000023    1221T   NULL    1993-12-10 00:00:00.000 Y
00043000    JOHNSON BROTHERS LIQUOR COMPANY 1999 SHEPARD ROAD   NULL    St. Paul    NULL    NULL    55116-3210  GB  410810551   0008725 00043000    2042T   NULL    1993-12-31 00:00:00.000 Y
000590  North Pacific Supply Co Inc 16250 SE Evelyn St  NULL    Clackamas   NULL    NULL    97015-9515  NULL    930430692   0042585 000590  4548T   NULL    1978-12-31 00:00:00.000 Y
```

Expected Value

```
'SystemKey' 'CompanyName'   'PhysicalAddressLine1'  'PhysicalAddressLine2'  'PhysicalCity'  'PhysicalStateCode' 'PhysicalProvince'  'PhysicalZipCode'   'PhysicalCountryCode'   'TaxId' 'AU'    'SystemID'  'OfficerID' 'MainPhone' 'OpenDate'  'ChangeFlag'
'15524499'  'Valley Medical Center' 'hfdfsffgsdhfdsfgsdfgsdfhgdhfgsdfgsgfjgdsContactAddressLine2dsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsddsdsds'  'NULL'  'Renton'    'ww'    'NULL'  'ww12'  'US'    'NULL'  '0042585'   '15524499'  '6577T' 'NULL'  '2015-10-15 00:00:00.000'   'Y'
'0007736-000'   '9700 Pico Corp'    '9700 W Pico Blvd'  'NULL'  'Los Angeles'   ' ' 'NULL'  '90035-4700'    'US'    '954456131' '0007031'   '0007736-000'   '0193T' 'NULL'  '1981-12-29 00:00:00.000'   'Y'
'00088700'  'GATEWAY, INC.' '14303 Gateway Place'   'NULL'  'POWAY' 'NULL'  'CA'    '92064' 'CA'    '421249184' '0008725'   '00088700'  '1209T' 'NULL'  '1996-08-26 00:00:00.000'   'Y'
'00002400'  'Nash Finch Company'    '7600 France Ave S' 'NULL'  'Minneapolis'   'NULL'  'ww'    '554355924' 'CA'    '410431960' '0008725'   '00002400'  '1289T' 'NULL'  '1993-10-22 00:00:00.000'   'Y'
'00006000'  'BAE SYSTEMS, Inc.' '1601 Research Blvd'    'NULL'  'ROCKVILLE' 'NULL'  'MD'    '20850-3173'    'CA'    '223537950' '0062635'   '00006000'  '1236T' 'NULL'  '1993-11-23 00:00:00.000'   'Y'
'00008714'  'Schreiber Foods Inc and Affiliated'    'PO Box 19010'  'NULL'  'GREEN BAY' 'WI'    'NULL'  '54307-9010'    'US'    '391017450' '0048114'   '00008714'  '0083T' 'NULL'  '2007-09-25 00:00:00.000'   'Y'
'00013455'  'Border States Industries, Inc.'    '105 25th Street N' 'fkjsdhjksdhfjsdkfjks'  'Fargo' 'NULL'  'NULL'  '58102' 'NULL'  '450275004' '0057221'   '00013455'  '1815T' 'NULL'  '2010-09-30 00:00:00.000'   'Y'
'000160000023'  'Target Corporation'    '1000 Nicollet Mall'    'NULL'  'MINNEAPOLIS'   'MN'    'NULL'  '55402' 'US'    '043327228' '0008725'   '000160000023'  '1221T' 'NULL'  '1993-12-10 00:00:00.000'   'Y'
'00043000'  'JOHNSON BROTHERS LIQUOR COMPANY'   '1999 SHEPARD ROAD' 'NULL'  'St. Paul'  'NULL'  'NULL'  '55116-3210'    'GB'    '410810551' '0008725'   '00043000'  '2042T' 'NULL'  '1993-12-31 00:00:00.000'   'Y'
'000590'    'North Pacific Supply Co Inc'   '16250 SE Evelyn St'    'NULL'  'Clackamas' 'NULL'  'NULL'  '97015-9515'    'NULL'  '930430692' '0042585'   '000590'    '4548T' 'NULL'  '1978-12-31 00:00:00.000'   'Y'
```

Comment: Can you please what it does and line break up. In addition to this, the above regexp works only 90%. It didn't work for end word of the lines and start word of the line from line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(\t)|^|$
```

and replace with `(?{1}'$1':')`.

It matches and captures a tab into Group 1, and if it matches the tab is enclosed in single quotes. Else, start and end of lines are matched and in that case, a single `'` is inserted at those positions.

**Details**

- `(\t)` - Capturing group 1: a tab
- `|` - or
- `^` - start of line
- `|` - or
- `$` - end of line.

Replacement:

- `(?{1}` - if Group 1 matches

  - `'$1'` - replace with `'`, Group 1 value and `'`
  - `:` - else
  - `'` - replace with `'`
- `)` - end of the conditional replacement pattern.

See the screenshot:

[image]